# Lower bounds on the magnitude of ${\rm erf}(z)$ function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, error-function

We are looking for the lower bound on the
\begin{align}
|{\rm erf}(z)|  \ge ???
\end{align}
Here ${\rm erf}(z)$ is the [complex-valued error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)

We know that around $z=0$ the function is linear, and for $z \to \infty$, it is exponential.
So we expect a bound of the form
\begin{align}
|{\rm erf}(z)|  \ge C |z| e^{ - |z|^2}
\end{align}
However, I was not able to locate anything of this form in the literature.

Comment: You might clarify what you mean by the term $Cze^{z^2}$ when $z$ is complex.

Comment: Your link is titled "Error function."

Comment: @Aruralreader Thanks. I corrected it

Comment: $\operatorname{erf}(z)$ has an [infinite number of zeros](http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.13.i) with arbitrarily large magnitude.

Comment: @Gary thanks.  I didn't know this.  This is basically saying that if a non-trivial lower bound exists, it would have to hit these zeros.